# resume conjure-up opensatck installation

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

for some reason my "conjure-up openstack" installation interrupted after the 16 machine task started but not finished, (3 of them come to state 'active')
is it possible to resume the installation? (after system reboot)
I can see the 16 items from "lxc list" output, and there's a controller available from "juju list-controllers"
can I just re-run the "conjure-up openstack" and select the previous controller to resume the installation?
or should I remove/delete the previous tasks then start from a new installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been brainstorming the best way to approach this. However, at this time support for continuing an install is not there. Though, juju status will probably show you a deployed cloud but the final post processing steps didn't complete so you would have to import glance images and setup neutron networking yourself.

Comment: then how can I remove the uncompleted installation ? (after "conjure-up openstack" command)
so that I don't need to re-install the OS again.

Comment: Run `conjure-down`

Comment: after "conjure-down", there's controller exist in the "juju list-containers" output, should i remove them manually?

Comment: during the installation, there are 2GB+ downloaded and 16  VMs installed, where are these created files located?